# Flux of a vector field $F(x,y,z)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I have a circle in the $yz$-plane centered at $(0,2,0)$ with radius $1$.

The surface $\Sigma$ is obtained by rotating the circle around the $z$-axis.

I want calculate the flux of the vector field $F(x,y,z)=(\sqrt{y^2+z^2},\arctan(x+z),\cfrac{(z+1)^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}})$

We can parametrize the circle with $\gamma(t)=(0,2+\sin{t},\cos{t})$ with $t \in [0,2\pi]$ so the surface $\Sigma=(-\sin{v}(2+\sin{u}), \cos{v}((2+\sin{u}), \cos{u})$ with $u,v \in [0,2\pi]$.

Can I use Stoke's theorem to solve this problem?

Comment: It's a closed torus? I would use divergence theorem.

Comment: $divF=\frac{2(z+1)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ so $\int \int \int div F dx dy dz$?

Comment: Well that's a nicer looking object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot use the Stoke's theorem for this problem. You can however use the divergence theorem for this type of problem though. It states that:

$$flux = \iint_\Sigma F\cdot dS = \iiint \nabla \cdot F dV$$

which essentially translates to the flux of the field $F$ through the closed surface is equal to the divergence of the field $F$ through the entire volume enclosed by that surface.

Note that the RHS is easier to calculate than the LHS because

$$\begin{aligned}
\cfrac{\partial F_1}{\partial x} &= 0\\
\cfrac{\partial F_2}{\partial y} &= 0\\
\cfrac{\partial F_3}{\partial z} &= \cfrac{2(z+1)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}
\end{aligned}$$

Now, we have to parameterize the volume of the torus (not the area as you have already done). This is easily done by further noting that parameterizing the area of circle means that we have a radius $a \in [0,1]$ as opposed to $a=1$ on the boundary.

Thus, $\gamma(u,a) = (0, 2+a\sin{u},a\cos{u})$ with $u \in [0,2\pi), a \in [0,1]$. And the volume $V(u,a,v)=(-\sin{v}(2+a \sin{u}), \cos{v}(2+a \sin{u}), a \cos{u})$ with $u \in [0,2\pi), v \in [0,2\pi), a \in [0,1]$.

EDIT: Before we revisit the integral, we first need to compute the Jacobian for this transformation from $(x,y,z)$ coordinates to $(u,v,a)$ coordinates.

$$\begin{aligned}
Jacobian&=\begin{vmatrix}\cfrac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \cfrac{\partial x}{\partial v} & \cfrac{\partial x}{\partial a}\\
\cfrac{\partial y}{\partial u} & \cfrac{\partial y}{\partial v} & \cfrac{\partial y}{\partial a}\\
\cfrac{\partial z}{\partial u} & \cfrac{\partial z}{\partial v} & \cfrac{\partial z}{\partial a} \end{vmatrix}\\
&= \begin{vmatrix}-a\cos{u}\sin{v} & -\cos{v}(2+a \sin{u}) & -\sin{u}\sin{v}\\
a \cos{u} \cos{v} & -\sin{v}(2+a \sin{u}) & \sin{u}\cos{v}\\
-a\sin{u} & 0 & \cos{u} \end{vmatrix}\\
&= a\cos^2{u}\sin^2{v}(2+a\sin{u}) + a\sin^2{u} \cos^2{v}(2+a\sin{u})+a \sin^2{u}\sin^2{v}(2+a\sin{u})+a\cos^2{u}\cos^2{v}(2+a\sin{u})\\
&= a\sin^2{v}(2+a\sin{u})+a\cos^2{v}(2+a\sin{u})\\
&= a(2+a\sin{u})
\end{aligned}$$

Then we can rewrite our volume differential using this Jacobian as $dxdydz=a(2+a\sin{u})dudadv$.

$$\begin{aligned}
flux&=\iiint \cfrac{2(z+1)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} dV\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 \int_0^{2\pi} \cfrac{2a \cos{u} + 2}{a\sin{u}+2}(a(2+a\sin{u}))du da dv \\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 \int_0^{2\pi} (2a^2 \cos{u} + 2a)du da dv \\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 4 \pi a da dv\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi} 2 \pi dv\\
&=4\pi^2
\end{aligned}$$

Note how much easier the RHS of the divergence theorem is compared to the monstrosity that is the LHS in this case.

Comment: and in this case? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1832133/stokes-theorem-for-the-flux-through-a-surface

Comment: I'm not going to do that problem for you as these are obviously homework assignments. However, in that problem too you would calculate the divergence of $F$, convert your volume $V$ from $(x,y,z)$ coordinates to something more suitable for your volume, and then compute $flux=\iiint \nabla\cdot F dV$ using the divergence theorem exactly as in this problem.

Comment: You suggest use divergence theorem.But when can I use stoke's theorem?

Comment: [Look at Stokes' theorem](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/StokesTheorem.aspx) again. It is only applicable if you have a surface bounded by a simple, closed, smooth boundary curve, and you are computing the surface integral of the curl of $F$. In both questions, you are working with flux - a concept directly tied into the divergence theorem - on a surface with no boundary curve.

Comment: when you calculate the integral above and change the coordinates dx dy dz in da du dv , I consider the Jacobian of the trasformation?

Comment: $$\begin{aligned}
flux&=\iiint \cfrac{2(z+1)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} dV\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 \int_0^{2\pi} \cfrac{2a \cos{u} + 2}{a\sin{u}+2} (2+asinu) du da dv \\
\end{aligned}$$=$4{\pi}^2$?

Comment: @GiuliaB. You got it exactly correct! I forgot about the Jacobian when making that transformation of variables. Indeed, that simplifies the integral considerably, and makes it quite easy to compute by hand. My edits confirm your comment.

Comment: I don't understand how to use the divergence in the other problem.Can you give me a suggest there?